# How to convert a vector of arrays into 4D array?

Tags: image, julia

I'm trying to play a little bit with Knet.jl and CNNs. Every example I found requires the input for CNN to be in the form of [dim1, dim2, n_of_channels, N] where N is a number of the actual images.
I'm a bit new to Julia and I don't know how to accomplish this.

I loaded images from some private directory and pushed them to a vector, so that their length is N.

```
images = Vector()
for img_file in readdir(dir)
    img = load("$dir/$img_file")
    images = vcat(images, [img])
end

typeof(image)
"320-element Array{Any,1}"
```

However in the following example xtrn is stored as 28x28x1x60000 Array and that is what I would like to accomplish with the private dataset.

```
using Knet; include(Knet.dir("data","mnist.jl"))
xtrn,ytrn,_,_= mnist()

typeof(xtrn)
Array{Float32,4}
```

I'm aware of functions as *channelview*, *reshape* and it's seems they should provide solution but I played with them a bit and got *DimensionMismatch* error all the time. I guess there's something I miss.

Comment: Side note: in a case like this, use `push!(images, img)` instead of that `vcat` horror looking too much like Matlab :) And maybe `sizehint!` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the files you are using in your example. But I would use `cat` in conjunction with a generator. Here's an example of something you can do:

```
julia> reduce((x,y)->cat(x, y, dims=4), rand(3,3) for _ in 1:3)
3×3×1×3 Array{Float64,4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 0.366818  0.847529  0.209042
 0.281807  0.467918  0.68881 
 0.179162  0.222919  0.348935

[:, :, 1, 2] =
 0.0418451  0.256611  0.609398
 0.65166    0.281397  0.340405
 0.11109    0.387638  0.974488

[:, :, 1, 3] =
 0.454959  0.37831   0.554323
 0.213613  0.980773  0.743419
 0.133154  0.782516  0.669733
```

In order to do this with your files, this might work (untested):

```
images = reduce((x,y)->cat(x, y, dims=4), load(joinpath(dir, img_file)) for img_file in readdir(dir))
```

BTW. You should not initialize vectors like this:

```
images = Vector()
```

This makes an untyped container, which will have very bad performance. Write e.g.

```
images = Matrix{Float32}[]
```

This initializes an empty vector of `Matrix{Float32}`s.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. However, the single values are stored as (e.g.) RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.9,0.9) and hence, the entire Array has dimensions in the form of [dim1, dim2, 1, N]. And what I wanted is the form of [dim1, dim2, 3 (because of RGB), N] so that the single value stored in an array is just Float. Any ideas for the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to fill in the answer of DNF, this code results in Array in the form of [dim1, dim2, 1, N]:

```
images = reduce((x,y)->cat(x, y, dims=4), load(joinpath(dir, img_file)) for img_file in readdir(dir))
```

I wanted the 3rd dimension to be the channel and hence, the expected output is produced by:

```
images = reduce((x, y) -> cat(x, y, dims=4), permutedims(channelview(load(joinpath(dir, img_file))), (2, 3, 1)) for img in readdir(dir))
```